# Keycloak in Kubernetes: 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable

Tags: docker, ssl, kubernetes, network-programming, keycloak

Following the instructions on the Keycloak docs site below, I'm trying to set up Keycloak to run in a Kubernetes cluster. I have an Ingress Controller set up which successfully works for a simple test page. Cloudflare points the domain to the ingress controllers IP.

Keycloak deploys successfully (`Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990`), but when going to the domain I get a message from NGINX: `503 Service Temporarily Unavailable`.

https://www.keycloak.org/getting-started/getting-started-kube

Here's the Kubernetes config:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: keycloak-cip
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    name: keycloak
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/linode-loadbalancer-default-protocol: https
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/linode-loadbalancer-port-443: '{ "tls-secret-name": "my-secret", "protocol": "https" }'
spec:
  rules:
    - host: my.domain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: keycloak-cip
              servicePort: 8080
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - my.domain.com
      secretName: my-secret
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: keycloak
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: keycloak
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: keycloak
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: keycloak
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: keycloak
          image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:12.0.3
          env:
            - name: KEYCLOAK_USER
              value: "admin"
            - name: KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD
              value: "admin"
            - name: PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING
              value: "true"
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 8080
            - name: https
              containerPort: 8443
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /auth/realms/master
              port: 8080
            initialDelaySeconds: 90
            periodSeconds: 5
            failureThreshold: 30
            successThreshold: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 1
```

---

Edit:

TLS should be handled by the ingress controller.

--

Edit 2:

If I go into the controller using kubectl exec, I can do `curl -L http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth` which successfully retrieves the page:
`<title>Welcome to Keycloak</title>`. So I'm sure that keycloak is running. It's just that either traffic doesn't reach the pod, or keycloak doesn't respond.

If I use the ClusterIP instead but otherwise keep the call above the same, I get a `Connection timed out`. I tried both ports 80 and 8080 with the same result.

Comment: For me the issue was due to "readinessProbe" and "livenessProbe" that were failing

Answer (score 2):

The following configuration is required to run **keycloak** behind **ingress controller**:

```
- name: PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING
  value: "true"
- name: KEYCLOAK_HOSTNAME
  value: "my.domain.com"
```

So I think adding correct **KEYCLOAK_HOSTNAME** value should solve your issue.

I had a similar issue with Traefik Ingress Controller:
**[Can't expose Keycloak Server on AWS with Traefik Ingress Controller and AWS HTTPS Load Balancer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67828817/cant-expose-keycloak-server-on-aws-with-traefik-ingress-controller-and-aws-http)**

You can find the full code of my configuration here:
**https://github.com/skyglass-examples/user-management-keycloak**

Answer (score 1):

Hello Have you tried to add this line :

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
```

it looks like it is missing from your config file which result in 503 error, check [this](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#backend-protocol) for more input on the config of K8s.

Comment: I tried both http and https and neither helped unfortunately. I should point out that Keycloak itself should use http. TLS should terminate at the ingress.

Comment: but have you tried with the right syntax I mean with quotes and everything?

Comment: Yup, I copy pasted the line. Although I think it should be "http" so that TLS terminates at the ingress. Btw I placed it right after the other annotations in the Ingress under `metadata > annotations`. 

I wonder if it has something to do with the ports being wrong, or if Keycloak simply isn't listening. At least in standalone mode it will only bind to local addresses. I didn't see anything about that in the docs above though.